# Can not talk into My Headset when Dialing Out from Outlook Contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Headset problem when dialling Out from Outlook Contacts.

To spare myself from dialling wrong numbers I dial out from Microsoft Outlook 10 Contacts, using an internal modem card (Conexant CX-9Z-NR0134) using a landline. I have a Logitech h800 wireless headset (via USB)

It dials out fine from Microsoft Outlook, when the other party picks up I hear him on my headset, but the other party does not hear me if I pick up then my telephone receiver I could continue on with the conversation, but whatever I speak into my headset is not heard by the other party.

I don’t have this headset problem if I call out via internet, only when using my land line
Is there a Windows 7 Microphone setup that is missing Or a problem with my modem driver?

Can someone please help me?